# How to use one CSV file to pass data into multiple HTTP Samples in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to pass test data from one csv file to multiple http requests like first row should take by 1st http sample and second row should take by 2nd http sample.Please help how to use this in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these:

1. Add your CSV Dataset config in test plan level
2. Define Thread group (enough thread, ramp-up, duration)
3. Under thread group, add your requests or samples.
4. Put your CSV file in the JMeter bin directory.
5. Use those variables (defined in CSV Dataset) in your requests.

**Hint:**

CSV Data set Config:

[image]

Http Request sampler:

[image]

Comment: Here unable to see image and i've tried the same but as per my question i want to pass first row for first request and second row for second request ,,,like this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what problems are you facing right now? I have already given the answer for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read a specific (arbitrary) line from a file with each Sampler you can use i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for this like:

- `${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(0),)}` - read 1st string
- `${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(1),)}` - read 2nd string
- `${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(2),)}` - read 3rd string
- etc.

Demo:

[image: Groovy read arbitrary line from file]

[File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) method is a [Groovy JDK enhancement](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) to provide some ["syntactic sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) on top of "normal" Java to make developers lives easier.

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to get started with using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: I'm not able to see uploaded image,showing..Site is moved to anotherThis site can’t be reached

The webpage at https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpZHt.png might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.